# How to prevent client on mac terminal (command prompt window) from returning null and making it wait to send text messages

Tags: java, cmd, client

I'm trying to make a program that will send and receive text messages (UTF 8 strings) to each other similar to two phones texting each other using two separate threads inside two separate .java files (one client one server) (eclipse), but the text messages will appear on the command prompt (mac terminal output)

Screenshot of null (see window on the right):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a734wf2yrym8m46/Screen%20Shot%202017-04-04%20at%202.24.59%20PM.png?dl=0

The left window will be the server and the right window will be the client in the screenshot

The command line arguments for the server will be:

```
java DirectMessengerServer -l 3000
```

The command line arguments for the client will be:

```
java DirectMessengerClient 3000
```

The "-l" will be used later to differentiate between client and server later (ignore this for now)

The port number will be 3000.

Code of client (DirectMessengerClient.java):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class DirectMessengerClient
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Thread Client = new Thread () 
        {
            public void run ()
            {   
                System.out.println("Client thread is now running");
                ServerSocket server_socket = null;
                Socket client_socket = null;
                Socket smtpSocket = null;  
                DataOutputStream outputstream = null;
                DataInputStream inputstream = null;

                try
                {
                    System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                    int port_number1= Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
                    // ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
                    System.out.println("Listening for connections..");
                    System.out.println( "Listening on port: " + Integer.toString( port_number1 ) );
                    client_socket= server_socket.accept();
                    BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
                    PrintWriter output= new PrintWriter( client_socket.getOutputStream(), true );
                    outputstream = new DataOutputStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream());
                    inputstream = new DataInputStream(smtpSocket.getInputStream());
                    String input_line= reader.readLine();
                    System.out.println( "Received from client: " );
                    System.out.println( input_line );
                    output.println( input_line );
                }
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                }
            //server.close();
            // }
            }

        };
        Client.start();
    }
}
```

Code of Server (DirectMessengerServer.java):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class DirectMessengerServer
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Thread Server = new Thread () 
        {
            public void run ()
            {   
                System.out.println("Server thread is now running");
                ServerSocket server_socket = null;
                Socket client_socket;
                String message1;

                for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
                {
                    if(args[i].equals("-l"))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                            int port_number1= Integer.valueOf(args[i+1]);
                            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
                            System.out.println("Listening for connections..");
                            System.out.println( "Listening on port: " + Integer.toString( port_number1 ) );
                            Socket socket = listener.accept();
                            client_socket= server_socket.accept();
                            BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
                            PrintWriter output= new PrintWriter( client_socket.getOutputStream(), true );
                            String input_line= reader.readLine();
                            System.out.println( "Received from client: " );
                            System.out.println( input_line );
                            output.println( input_line );
                        }
                        catch ( Exception e )
                        {
                            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                        }
                    //server.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        Server.start();
    }
}
```

My question is: The client doesn't wait for the text messages and instead returns null for some reason (not sure why). Is there a way to make the client wait for text messages before exiting and returning null?